# Como fazer para os dados sugeridos do <datalist> só apareçam ao ser digitados?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>



  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <form action="">
    <label for="myFruit">What's your favorite fruit?</label>
    <input type="text" name="myFruit" id="myFruit" list="mySuggestion">
    <datalist id="mySuggestion">
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Blackberry</option>
      <option>Blueberry</option>
      <option>Lemon</option>
      <option>Lychee</option>
      <option>Peach</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
    </datalist>

    <input type="submit" value="de">
  </form>

<script>


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

No exemplo acima quando você clica na caixa de texto(`input="text"`) de imediato já aparece os dados sugerido automaticamente pelo `<datalist>`, mas o que eu gostaria neste caso seria apenas quando o usuário começar a digitar, ai sim os dados apareciam.

Comment: Algo [Assim](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete)?

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava procurando! agora sim, valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: De nada, força ;)